# python pandas データの参照、検索、取得およびファイル書き出し

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

ほぼ初心者のため、ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

とあるファイル（`length.txt`、約40万行×2列、画像左参照）を１行ずつ参照してデータ取得し、そのデータをもとに別のファイル（`effect.txt`、約4万行×2列、画像右参照）のデータを検索、照合し、データをテキストファイルに書き出すということを行いたいです。

具体的には、以下の流れです。

1. `length.txt`内の`locus`列、`length`列の値を１行ずつ取得。この例では、１行目は`locus`が1で、`length`が191です。
2. `effect.txt`内の`snp`列で、１．で取得した`locus`の値を検索し、照合した`locus`値の行の`effect`列の値を、１．で取得した`length`個分（どの要素も大体200個前後です）そこから下の`effect`列の値を取得する。この例では、-0.03460835、0、-0.03001576、・・・、0、0、0、0.2164842、・・・（全部で191個分）。
3. 取得した`effect`列の値を、行方向に書き出す。
4. この作業を`length`列の終わりまで行い、テキストファイル（タブ区切り）として書き出す。すなわち約40万行×約200列のデータです。（空白要素は`#N/A`や`-`で表現したいです）

初心者ながら以下のようなコードを書いてみましたがうまくいきません。

```py
import pandas as pd

length = pd.read_table('length.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
effect = pd.read_table('effect.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

with open('effect_out.txt', "w") as ew:
　　for i, j in zip(length['locus'], length['length']):
　　　　effect[effect['snp'] == i]
　　　　effect.head(j).T
　　　　for ext in effect:
　　　　　　ew.write(ext+'\n')
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「うまくいかない」は具体的にどのような問題がありますか？

Comment: effect_out.txt の画像も載せていただけますでしょうか？

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございました。無事できました。具体的なデータもあげていただき恐縮です。こんなにシンプルに書けるなんて驚きました。

Comment: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) などが, 
スタック・オーバーフロー > ヘルプセンター に載ってます。参考に。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length.txt` と `effect.txt` は適当に作成(TAB区切り)。

```py
import pandas as pd

length = pd.read_table('length.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
effect = pd.read_table('effect.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

effect = effect.set_index('snp')
dfx = length.apply(lambda i: effect.loc[i['locus']:i.sum()-1, 'effect'].reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
dfx.to_csv('effect_out.txt', sep='\t', na_rep='#N/A', index=False, header=None)
```

**length.txt**

```
locus   length
1   10
2   10
3   10
4   10
```

**effect.txt**

```
snp effect
1   1
2   3
3   -5
4   0
5   14
6   -1
7   8
8   6
9   -2
10  0
```

**effect_out.txt**

```
1.0 3.0 -5.0    0.0 14.0    -1.0    8.0 6.0 -2.0    0.0
3.0 -5.0    0.0 14.0    -1.0    8.0 6.0 -2.0    0.0 #N/A
-5.0    0.0 14.0    -1.0    8.0 6.0 -2.0    0.0 #N/A    #N/A
0.0 14.0    -1.0    8.0 6.0 -2.0    0.0 #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
```